# If $G$ is a graph, $G$ is not connected, then there are at least $2$ connected components of $G$.

Tags: graph-theory

If $G$ is a graph, $G$ is not connected, then there are at least $2$ connected components of $G$. I still cannot understand this statement. By definition of graph in my book, $G$ is a pair of $(V,E)$ where $V$ is vertices and $E$ is set of underordered pair of elements of $V$. If I set $V$ to be 3 vertices (1,2,3) and $E$ to be the edge connecting 1 and 2 but not the rest, then $G$ is not connected but there is only 1 connected component..? Sorry if it seems trivial cause my answer proof did not explain why.

Comment: What are your definitions of connected graph and connected component?

Comment: For connected graph it is any pair of vertices has a path connecting to it in the $G$ graph. For connected component I do not have it in my notes but after googling it should just mean a subgraph which is connected.

Comment: Great, I was just checking that we were using the same defs.

Comment: I take it you're not allowing the empty graph?

Comment: So is the graph consisting of a single vertex and no edges connected or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the contrapositive, if $G$ has exactly one connected component, then any two points belong to this component, hence they are connected by some path. This is way the graph being connected *means*, by definition.

Here's a fun exercise that you can prove: the relation $v \sim w$ if there exists a path $\xi$ from $v$ to $w$ is an equivalence relation, and the partition it induces is exactly the one composed of connected components.

Comment: I still do not understand why it implies $G$ is connected when $G$ has exactly one connected component?

Comment: Why do any two points belong to this subgraph?

Comment: Take any two points. They must be in the same component. What does this mean? That they have a path from one to the other! This works for any two points, so they are all connected to each other by some path. This is the definition of connectedness.

Comment: @ilovewt because $G$ is partitioned into connected components: any point belongs to some connected component, and no point can belong to two of these at the same time (the exercise I left proves this as an immediate consequence :P)

Comment: So you mean if $G$ has exactly one connected component, then $G$ must be that connected component?

Comment: Exactly, that's it!

Comment: Oh.. so I am missing out on the definition of connected components! Well, I really thought we can consider a disconnected graph but it has ONE connected graph inside, in which case, it makes me wonder why need at least 2 connected components haha.